# What causes the failure to protect a route in this React.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am making a chat app with React 18 and Firebase 9.

The chat route - which is the root app - is supposed to be accessible only after authentication.

In `App.js` I have:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  RouterProvider,
  Navigate
} from 'react-router-dom';
import RootLayout from './layouts/RootLayout';
import AuthLayout from './layouts/AuthLayout';
import Chat from './pages/Chat';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import { AuthContext } from './contexts/AuthContext';

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route index
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute>
            <Chat />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        } />

      <Route path="auth" element={<AuthLayout />}>
        <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
);

function App() {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      return <Navigate to="/auth/login" />;
    }
    return children
  };

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={ router } ProtectedRoute={ ProtectedRoute } />
  );
}

export default App;
```

In `src\contexts\AuthContext.js` I have:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebaseConfig";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

export const AuthContext = createContext();
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const unSubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      console.log(user);
    });

    return () => {
      unSubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I use the AuthContextProvider in index.js:

```
import { AuthContextProvider } from './contexts/AuthContext';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <AuthContextProvider>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </AuthContextProvider>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

The Chrome console throws this error from `App.js`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ProtectedRoute is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### UPDATE

This version of App.js throws a `React Hook "useContext" cannot be called at the top level` error:

```
const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, currentUser }) => {
  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Navigate to="/auth/login" />;
  }
  return children
};

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route index
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute currentUser={ currentUser }>
            <Chat />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        } />

      <Route path="auth" element={<AuthLayout />}>
        <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}
```

Comment: 1. You shouldn't declare a component inside another component 2. Your user doesn't have a time to load, because you immediately redirect. You should show a loading state

Comment: You seem to be expecting RouterProvider to accept arbitrary properties and make them accessible to the elements used to create the routes, despite there being no obvious mechanism for the name binding and the fact that the routes are created _before_ being passed to the provider.

Answer (score 1):

In your updated version of App.js, you've made some improvements to handle the useContext issue and passing currentUser to ProtectedRoute. However, you're still encountering an issue with ProtectedRoute being undefined.

Let's address this and make necessary adjustments.
Move the ProtectedRoute function outside of the App component so that it's defined before you use it.

```js
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, currentUser }) => {
  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Navigate to="/auth/login" />;
  }
  return children;
};

function App() {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
        <Route
          index
          element={<ProtectedRoute currentUser={currentUser}><Chat /></ProtectedRoute>}
        />
        <Route path="auth" element={<AuthLayout />}>
          <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    )
  );

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}
  export default App;
```

By moving ProtectedRoute outside of App, it will be defined before it's used in the JSX.

You are now passing currentUser as a prop to ProtectedRoute in the updated code. This allows ProtectedRoute to access currentUser and determine if the user is authenticated.

With these adjustments, the error should be resolved, and the ProtectedRoute component should now be defined and functional within your React app.

Answer (score 0):

For RouterProvider from react-router-dom you don't have ProtectedRoute prop.

Comment: Where in the code?